# Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module Expected directory: node-v88-darwin-x64-unknown Found: [node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown]

Tags: node.js, grpc

I have issue about missmatch node version for requirement load gRPC.
**This issue appear when i run node js server using pm2, but when i did it using nodemon and node command, it running well**

```
Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-v88-darwin-x64-unknown
Found: [node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown]
```

i have already change my node version default to same as project, using:

`nvm alias default x.x.x`

but the result same,

Also i have already `rm -rf node_modules` and run `npm install` again, but the result is same,

Last, i have already doing `npm rebuild` and the result same error.

What want i know is, how we can solve this issue whatever missmatch version?
Why i already doing change default node version in global using nvm, but it still look like not change for project, look like it have some other settings/configuration that i did not done

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `grpc` is installed for Node 10, but you are trying to use it in Node 16. You can explicitly install it for Node 16 by running

```
npm install --target=16.0.0
```

---

Please note that the `grpc` package is deprecated with the recommendation that you use `@grpc/grpc-js` instead.